# MySQL: create new table with frequencies based on data from original table

Tags: mysql, select, distinct, create-table

There are two important fields `kernel` and `property` in the table `mydata`:

I want to **CREATE a new table** `myresults` with columns `rightTwoKernelSymbols`, `property` and `frequency` based only on `mydata` table so, that it displays the frequency of right two letters among `kernel` column. (property values should be equivalent, otherwise count separately)

**So, using another words:**
Here is 'mydata' table. I modify 'kernel' column by leaving only two right symbols in each cell.
Using this table, I want to count distinct pairs (kernel, property) and save the data into `myresults` table.

Example:

**mydata Table**

```
czzzaa - 123
abc80 - 123
aaaaaaaa - 123
zz5 - 123
abc80 - 456
```

**modified Table**

```
aa - 123
80 - 123
aa - 123
z5 - 123
80 - 456
```

**myresults Table**

```
aa - 123 - 2 // czzzaa and aaaaaaaa - total two times (123 is the same)
80 - 123 - 1
z5 - 123 - 1
80 - 456 - 1 //we don't count abc80 and abc80 together, because 123 is different from 456
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here is my answer on my own question. Please let me know if there are any pitfalls that weren't mentioned.

```
CREATE TABLE results AS SELECT right(kernel, 2) as two , property, COUNT(*) as count FROM mydata GROUP BY two, property ORDER BY count DESC;
```